# Integration by parts on $\int_{0}^\infty t \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt $

Tags: integration

I'd like to integrate

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty t \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt 
\end{align}

Which looks like something that needs to solved by integration by parts.

Integration by parts claims

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty udv = uv - \int_{0}^\infty vdu
\end{align}

If I let $u= e^{-\lambda t}$ and $v=t\lambda$

Then

$$
\begin{align}
t \lambda e^{-\lambda t}- \int_0^\infty t \lambda  du &= t \lambda e^{-\lambda t}- \int_0^\infty t \lambda  du \\
&= t \lambda e^{-\lambda t} - (t\lambda e^{-\lambda t})\big|_0^\infty
\end{align}
$$

But I don't know what it means to evaluate at $e^{\lambda t} = \infty$ and it equal to $0$?

Some help understanding what the proper approach is would be awesome.

---

Thanks everybody for the help. It makes much more sense now :)

Comment: What is your definition of an infinite integral? It is common to define $$\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$$ as $$\lim_{a\to \infty}\int_0^a f(x)\, dx.$$
That is, you integrate the function on a finite interval, then push the boundary.

Comment: second page of [this](https://mast.queensu.ca/~stat455/lecturenotes/set4.pdf) pdf shows the result I'm trying to get. I just can't follow the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take the limit as $t\rightarrow\infty$. Suppose that $\lambda>0,$ then setting $\color{red}{du}=e^{-\lambda t}$ and $v=t\lambda$ and integrating by parts

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty t \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt 
\end{align}=\int_{0}^{\infty}vdu=vu\big|_{t=0}^{t\rightarrow\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}udv$$
$$=\left[t\lambda\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{-\lambda}\right]_{t=0}^{t\rightarrow\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda\frac{e^{-\lambda t}}{-\lambda}dt$$
$$=\left[-te^{-\lambda t}\right]_{t=0}^{t\rightarrow\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}dt$$
$$=(0-0)-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda t}\big|_{t=0}^{t\rightarrow\infty}=-\frac{1}{\lambda}(0-1)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$

where we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}e^{-\lambda t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}te^{-\lambda t}=0$

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me so far. Could you explain why your evaluating $uv$ from 0 to infinity?  The formula I have says  we have $uv - \int v du$ so I'm curious why we're integrating that first term.

Comment: The formula for integrating by parts is usually given in indefinite form, that is without the integration limits. If you have the integration limits, then you evaluate each term using the limits $0$ to infinity. We have $$\int_{a}^{b}udv=uv\big|_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}vdu$$

Comment: Ahhh makes sense. When I reread [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) with what you said in mind it makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The improper integral $I = \int_0^{\infty}f(t) \,dt$ can be defined as $$ I  = \lim_{a\to \infty} \int_0^a f(t) \, dt$$.

So you need to calculate $\int_0^a t\lambda e^{-\lambda t} \, dt$ and take the limit $a \to \infty $.

Answer (score 1):

First substitute $t\lambda = u$

Then you get $$\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{\infty}ue^{-u}du$$

Now apply integration by parts by taking $e^{-u}$ as the inegrable function and $u$ as the differentiable function.

$$\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(\lim_{u\to\infty}(-ue^{-u})-\lim_{u\to 0}(-ue^{-u})-\int_{0}^{\infty}(-1)\left(\frac{d}{du}(u)\right)e^{-u}\right)=\frac{1}{\lambda}(0+\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}du)=\frac{-1}{\lambda}(\lim_{u\to\infty}e^{-u}-\lim_{u\to 0}e^{-u}) =\frac{1}{\lambda} $$.

Note that you can also invoke the gamma function.
It is just $\frac{1}{\lambda}\Gamma(2)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$